# Looking for improvement on PHP split and combination function

Tags: php, arrays, split, combinations

Suppose I have a string such as this:

ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL (This string could have any length and amount of characters between dots)

I want to add the following combinations into an array.
ABC
ABC.DEF
ABC.DEF.GHI
ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL

So basically the string should be split with the dot character and then the individual sub-strings should be combined.

I have a function already, but in my opinion this seems too complicated to achieve the result.

```
$myarray = array();
$split = explode('.', 'that.string.with.dots');
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($split); $i++) {
    $string .= $split[$i];
    myarray[] = $string;
    $string .= '.';
}
```

Any suggestions on improving this?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: what's wrong with your current function?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. It just seems very complicated to achieve the result.

Comment: 5 lines seems too complicated for you? eek

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and might be better suited here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
$split = explode('.', 'that.string.with.dots');
for ($i = 1; $i < count($split); $i++) {
    $split[i] = $split[$i-1] . '.' . $split[i];
}
```

It just concats the current with the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that you are asking if there is a PHP function that will achieve this result with a single function call, but I don't think there is one.

You can rewrite the code as pritaeas did in his answer, to remove two lines of code, but it will still be the same concept.

Comment: Yes, that is what i was thinking actually.